# Making screenshots very fast and out of memory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, loops, bitmap

I am trying to make screenshots of my screen very fast.

So, I use this code in my main class

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 1;
    int screenshotsAmount = 0;
    List<Bitmap> screenshots = new List<Bitmap>();
    while (x == 1)
    {
        screenshots.Add(FullsizeScreenshot.makeScreenshot());
        Clipboard.SetImage(screenshots[screenshotsAmount]);
        Console.WriteLine("Screenshot " + screenshotsAmount + " has been made and added to the Bitmap list!");
        screenshotsAmount++;
    }
}
```

And I have a method in my .dll, that creates screenshots

```
// Class for making standard screenshots
public struct FullsizeScreenshot
{

    // Making fullscreen screenshot
    public static Bitmap makeScreenshot() 
    {
        Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);

            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            gfxScreenshot.Dispose();

            return screenshot;
    }
}
```

Everything works correct, but when the number of screenshots becomes bigger than 109, my program crash with System.ArgumentException

*An unhandled exception of type "System.ArgumentException" in System.Drawing.dll 
Additional information: Invalid parameter.*

This line throws it:
*gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);*
or this:
*Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);*

I tried to use using (Bitmap screenshot....) and .Dispose(), but it doesn't work correct, because these classes (Bitmap and Graphics) are classes and they just create links instead of making copies. As a result, when I dispose the Bitmap in makeScreenshot() it broke the Bitmap in my List.

So, what should I do? Maybe I should make a copy, but I don't know how.

Comment: No surprise that you are running out of memory, storing thousands of `Bitmap` objects in memory is not a good idea. Perhaps you should change your requirements...

Comment: Not thousand. I can use Thread.Sleep(100) and it still will crash

Comment: That statement doesn't make sense

Comment: @Jonesy He's saying that if he puts Thread.Sleep(100) in the while loop, the program will still crash.  That will slow it down so that it only creates ten bitmaps per second.  Presumably, it takes fewer than 100 seconds to crash, therefore the program is not "storing thousands of Bitmap objects in memory" before it crashes.  Whether or not the distinction between 100 bitmaps and 1000 bitmaps before the crash is important is perhaps another matter.

Comment: Even 100 screenshots will take quite a bit of memory. It depends on what library you are using, but using AForge with a webcam just 10 or so screen shots without disposing was eating up memory (no crash, but 120MB or so of memory used). Point being, run it long enough, and it *will* run out of memory. You need some kind of recycling strategy in place.

Comment: the error in the text (not the caption) is not OOM, though.

Comment: Maybe. But what can also happen with this code?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? If it's an infinite amount of screen shots in memory, I'm afraid that's off the cards.

Comment: i just tested it, after 177 screenshots it uses 1.8GB memory... that's really the only problem, the exception is just wrong (according to MSDN, they should only throw those if the enumeration value is illegal).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I am trying to make GIF animated screenshots. But I have to make a lot of screenshots first. (About 25-20 screenshots per second)

Comment: Either write them to a fast enough disk or keep them in memory as bytearrays, not as Bitmaps!

Comment: Adding them to the clipboard all the time is also probably a bad idea.

Comment: @TaW why would a byte array be smaller (without any encoding)?

Comment: Not smaller. But Bitmaps are old-fashioned GDI objects and therefore afaik subject to several restrictions. They are managed differently from normal .NET memory.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a display of 1920x1080, that's 2,073,600 pixels, there are 4 bytes per pixel in a `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` So that's 8,294,400 bytes, or around 8 MB. 109 images would be 872 MB. Surprised that's crashing there, but you get the idea, it's too much memory.

If you want to make an animated gif, think how large that's going to be, full screen? Well I hope you're not planing on that, that's not practical for a gif. After you take the screenshot, resize it down immediately to the target resolution so it takes less memory.

Comment: I am trying to make GIF animated screenshots. But I have to make a lot of screenshots first. (About 25-20 screenshots per second)

Comment: If that is the case, just saved them to a file_number_xx.png.  And when you're ready to compile them to an animation, load one at a time.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it right now. So, I will try. But I am thinking about some kind of refreshing temp.JPEG

Comment: Or resize down each shot ASAP as per my new comments.